# PHP natsort() not sorting my URLs as I think it should

Tags: php

I am trying to sort image URLs and send back the image which is alphabetically first to show as featured image. Here is the code I have so far:

```
$image_array = get_post_meta($postID, "image_array", true);
$thumbnail_array = array();
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($image_array ); $i++) {
        $thumbnail_array[] = $image_array [$i]['thumbnail'];
    }
    natsort($thumbnail_array);
    return $thumbnail_array[0];
```

First I retrieve the array of images which is a json file, then I put each thumbnail URL in a thumbnail_array which is then sorted and returned. This doesn't seem to work however, I tried to log $thumbnail_array[0] and $thumbnail_array[1] before and after the sorting and here is what I got as an example:

```
Before natsort:
[0]: https://example.com/staging/wp-content/uploads/2022/08/image2-263x350.jpeg
[1]: https://example.com/staging/wp-content/uploads/2022/08/image1-263x350.jpeg

After natsort: 
[0]: https://example.com/staging/wp-content/uploads/2022/08/image2-263x350.jpeg
[1]: https://example.com/staging/wp-content/uploads/2022/08/image1-263x350.jpeg
```

Nothing happens after the sort, shouldn't 1 come before 2? Why is this? Am I missing something obvious (probably yes)?

Comment: It sorts correctly, as seen here: https://onlinephp.io/c/53140 the problem is probably in other place in your code.

Comment: natsort doesn't disassociate the keys with their values. The array elements ARE sorted, but their keys are retained so when you're referenceing `[0]` you're still referencing that data value, despite now it is in a different offset position in the array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`natsort` retains key-value association:

```
$a = [
    'https://example.com/staging/wp-content/uploads/2022/08/image2-263x350.jpeg',
    'https://example.com/staging/wp-content/uploads/2022/08/image1-263x350.jpeg'
];

natsort($a);
var_dump($a);
```

```
array(2) {
  [1]=>
  string(74) "https://example.com/staging/wp-content/uploads/2022/08/image1-263x350.jpeg"
  [0]=>
  string(74) "https://example.com/staging/wp-content/uploads/2022/08/image2-263x350.jpeg"
}
```

So yes, `0` will still be the `0` value and so on, but their order changed within the array. You can reset the keys if you want to renumber the values:

```
natsort($thumbnail_array);
$thumbnail_array = array_values($thumbnail_array);
```

Comment: Thank you! I read about it but thought it was only when I had like "key => value" and not when I had an array of strings. This worked perfectly, good explanation!